# Simultenaously reading from two csv files into struct

Tags: c, arrays, csv, struct, io

So I have tried to write a function to load data from the file into an array of structs, and one of the fields of struct is an array of another struck type. Is it possible to read part of the data from one file (users.csv) and then (loans.csv). For now it has been giving me "Unable to open file '(null)'"

```
#define MaxUsers 1000

struct User {
    char* register_name;
    char* login; //unique for each
    unsigned int status; // librarian (special user) has status 0, others have 1
    unsigned int numberBorrowed;
    struct Book books_borrowed[MaxBorrowed]; //array of books borrowed by the user
};

struct UserArray {
    struct User* array; //pointer to an array of struct User
    unsigned int length; //length of an array of struct User
};

struct Book {
        char *title; //book title
        char *authors; //comma separated list of authors
        unsigned int year; // year of publication
        unsigned int copies; //number of copies the library has
        unsigned int status; //to tell whether it has been borrowed - 1 for borrowed, 0 if in library
};

struct User all_users[MaxUsers];
struct UserArray u_array = {&all_users[0], 0}; //hold pointer to all_users array and its length


int load_users(FILE* file)
{

  char *field;
  int i=0;
  FILE* fb;
  //open the CSV file
  file = fopen("users.csv","r");
  if(file == NULL)
  {
    printf("Unable to open file '%s'\n",file);
    exit(1);
  }
  char characters[400];
   //  process the data
  //     the file contains 5 fields in a specific order:
  //       register_name, login, status, numberBorrowed, array of struct Book
  //       separated by commas

  while(fgets(characters,400,file)) //need to write function getline() to jump to the next row while reading the cvs file* update - it works
  {
  //get register_name
    field=strtok(characters,",");
    all_users[i].register_name=malloc(strlen(field)+1);
    strcpy(all_users[i].register_name, field);
  //    get login
    field=strtok(NULL,",");
    all_users[i].login=malloc(strlen(field)+1);
    strcpy(all_users[i].login, field);
  // get status
    field=strtok(NULL,",");
    all_users[i].status=atoi(field);
  //  get numberBorrowed
    field=strtok(NULL,",");
    all_users[i].numberBorrowed=atoi(field);
  // get books
    fb = fopen("loans.csv","r");
    char* fieldB;
    int j=0;
    char book_chars[400];
    while (fgets(book_chars, 400, fb) && j<all_users[i].numberBorrowed)
    {
      field=strtok(book_chars,",");
      all_users[i].books_borrowed[j].title=malloc(strlen(field)+1);
      strcpy(all_users[i].books_borrowed[j].title, field);

      field=strtok(NULL,",");
      all_users[i].login=malloc(strlen(field)+1);
      strcpy(all_users[i].books_borrowed[j].authors, field);

      field=strtok(NULL,",");
      all_users[i].books_borrowed[j].year=atoi(field);

      field=strtok(NULL,",");
      all_users[i].books_borrowed[j].copies=atoi(field);

      field=strtok(NULL,",");
      all_users[i].books_borrowed[j].status=atoi(field);

      j++;
    }

    i++;
  }
  u_array.length=i;
  // close file
  fclose(file);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're misusing `file` in your error message. It's a pointer to a `FILE`, not a string. You'll only every print that error message that doesn't specify the file. That's not the issue, but it's an issue. Does the file named "users.csv" exist in the directory where you're running this program?

Comment: yeah, it does (thanks for pointing out ````file```` usage, I'll try remember next time

Answer (score 1):

If `fopen` is failing, you should show the error so the user knows why:

```
char *path = "users.csv"; 
file = fopen(path,"r");
if( file == NULL ){
    perror(path);
    exit(1);
}
```